# SNMP DateAndTime, what is expected for a null value

Tags: snmp, mib, pysnmp

I am working on the Agent side of SNMP, and I have a field that is a DateAndTime, which has the syntax:

DateAndTime (OCTET STRING) (SIZE (8 |11)). Hint: 2d-1d-1d,1d:1d:1d.1d,1a1d:1d

The varBind in question returns the timestamp of a certain type of error, which (hopefully) will never happen.

So my question is what the agent should return if the event has not occurred.  If I return an empty string, the constraints technically aren't met.

I am not an SNMP expert, so maybe this acceptable?

Changing the MIB to a different definition/Type is a possibility, if that is what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

The agent should return an error for the incoming requests, by setting `error-status` to a suitable value (`genErr` for example), and also set `error-index` to the proper index in the varbind.

```
PDU ::= SEQUENCE {
           request-id INTEGER (-214783648..214783647),

           error-status                -- sometimes ignored
               INTEGER {
                   noError(0),
                   tooBig(1),
                   noSuchName(2),      -- for proxy compatibility
                   badValue(3),        -- for proxy compatibility
                   readOnly(4),        -- for proxy compatibility
                   genErr(5),
                   noAccess(6),
                   wrongType(7),
                   wrongLength(8),
                   wrongEncoding(9),
                   wrongValue(10),
                   noCreation(11),
                   inconsistentValue(12),
                   resourceUnavailable(13),
                   commitFailed(14),
                   undoFailed(15),
                   authorizationError(16),
                   notWritable(17),
                   inconsistentName(18)
               },

           error-index                 -- sometimes ignored
               INTEGER (0..max-bindings),

           variable-bindings           -- values are sometimes ignored
               VarBindList
       }
```

Comment: If the object is tabular, then the entry would not exist, thus the answer would be correct. If the object is a scalar, this answer is not correct.

Comment: “If this object is a scalar, this answer is not correct”? You should shed some more light here, as I could not understand your comment at all.

Comment: Google "snmp scalar and tabular" for discussions. I tried to find a standard that "guarantees" that a scalar exists, but did not find one. RFC 3781 went so far as to define scalar object as having "exactly one instance", but it did not become a standard. If you do a GET on a scalar object that you have access to, you are guaranteed to get a value, unless the agent does not follow common practices.

Comment: @UweInnh LOL, I have been one of the SNMP vendors for years. I meant your description is probably wrong. My answer should work flawlessly for the scalar case, but like you found out, for tabular case there should be some extra handling.

Comment: @Uwe That's simply false. There's nothing wrong with reporting an error value for a scalar that cannot be resolved at this time. If there's logically no resource called "date and time" for some item, then logically the scalar "doesn't exist" (despite its potential availability being defined in the MIB) and responding to requests for it with `noSuchInstance` is perfectly cromulent. Refer to RFC 3416 4.2.1.

Comment: Note, @Lex, that this is not the same as populating the response PDU's error field, which is for meta-problems (framing, format, access constraints, implementation problems such as lack of memory) and is thus not appropriate here. If the software you vend is doing that for cases like this, it is non-compliant.

Comment: The above observations I've made are true for scalars and table cells alike.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you probably should post your own answer.

Comment: @LexLi I was on the verge of considering it but comments do exist to suggest improvements to existing answers and you're already very close :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was taught that you want your MIB to be useable. Having scalars appear (return a value) and disappear (return noSuchInstance) would not make it useable. It's like not being able to depend on RAM. Your program (NMS) would become unwieldy to handle all the errors. Is there a standard? I cannot find one right now. Is it wrong? Seems like that's opinion.

Comment: @UweInnh If the value doesn't exist, then the scalar _should_ disappear. If you don't want that, ensure a value is always available. I already cited a standard reference.

Answer (score -1):

The MIB should define EXACTLY what happens in all circumstances. It is the contract between the agent and manager. If it does not, it is a faulty MIB. If it is a MIB that someone is developing, it needs to be fixed. If it is a public MIB, tell us which, so we can check.